# Visual Studio Code disable angular auto complete

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code

can someone explain how you disable angular auto complete on visual studio code?

Cheers

Comment: Yep, it's annoying to have hundreds of angular attribute tags showing up in IntelliSense when trying to write plain HTML.

Comment: Please vote here for this feature: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/12301959-provide-an-option-in-the-html-editor-to-disable-an

Answer (score 4):

Open the editor settings and search for the 'angular1' you will find a config:

> "html.suggest.angular1": true

copy this line to user setting and edit it to:

> "html.suggest.angular1": false

Angular1 suggestion will be disable.